# Consumindo Mysql com javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

Tenho um banco de dados usando Mysql porem o lado do servidor não roda node, é possível consumir um banco de dados usando uma requisição Ajax por exemplo? Usando Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Não, você não deve realizar requisições ao banco de dados no frontend de sua aplicação, a muitos motivos para não se fazer algo desse tipo e a segurança é talvez maior delas.

A função Ajax em particular serve para realizar requisições ao seu backend onde a lógica de sua aplicação e transações com o banco de dados são realizadas, essa função não pode ser usada para realizar requisições ao banco de dados diretamente.

Caso seja um requisito usar o Javascript para realizar transações com o banco de dados, você deve criar uma aplicação backend com nodeJs para a realização dessas operações.

Comment: simm simm pensei em todos os motivos para fazer isso e desisti kkk mas é que por agora eu não posso desenvolver um backend vou ter que ficar com o JSON mesmo kkk 
Obrigado pela resposta.